# Script does not work correctly inside updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, tooltip

I have a script for displaying tooltips

```
 function BindToolTip(){
        $('.toolTip').hover(
    function () {
        this.tip = this.title;
        $(this).append(
        '<div class="toolTipWrapper">'
            + '<div class="toolTipTop"></div>'
            + '<div class="toolTipMid">'
                + this.tip
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="toolTipBtm"></div>'
        + '</div>'
    );
        this.title = '';
        this.width = $(this).width();
        $(this).find('.toolTipWrapper').css({ left: this.width - 22 })
        $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeIn(300);

    },
function () {
    $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeOut(100);
    $(this).children().remove();
    this.title = this.tip;
}
);
    }
```

aspx file look like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddNews" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">  
<ContentTemplate>
 <script type="text/javascript">
             Sys.Application.add_load(BindToolTip);
  </script>    
   <div class="toolTip" title="This is a simple tooltip made with jQuery"></div> 
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDate" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>                          
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListYearStart" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedStartDateChanged" CssClass="dropdown"> </asp:DropDownList>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I hover the div, it displays tooltip correctly, but after doing postback with dropdownlist, when I hover div first time it displays two tooltips, one is empty and other  tooltip with text behind the first. When I hover second time, it display only the empty tooltip. I know that if I remove line:  this.title = ''; from script it will work fine, but it is goint to display two tooltips, my custom one, and the default windows tooltip. How to solve it?

Comment: where do you call the `BindToolTip()` ?

Comment: I edited aspx, I use Sys.Application.add_load(BindToolTip);
in outer UpdatePanel

Comment: are you trying to hookup `BindToolTip` to execute everytime you have a partial postback?

Answer (score 1):

Write your script at last of the ContentTemplate. Like,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddNews" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">  
<ContentTemplate>    
<div class="toolTip" title="This is a simple tooltip made with jQuery"></div> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDate" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>                          
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListYearStart" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedStartDateChanged" CssClass="dropdown"> </asp:DropDownList>
<script type="text/javascript">
         Sys.Application.add_load(BindToolTip);
</script>    
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope it helps.
Don't forget to upvote it if it solves you problem.
Thanks.. :)